# Does NextJS copy images for export?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, static-site

I am creating a website that is meant to be a static website, but I have a photo gallery with descriptions on one page that I am using WordPress as the CMS. All the data is from WP is fetched using getStaticProps().

My question is, when you run `next export`, does Next export these images to the output folder? If not, the img link will not work, since it will link to my computer.

If that doesn't work, any thoughts as to how this can be solved without running a server?

Answer (score 0):

No, Next.js does not export the images files to the output folder. If your wordpress is already deployed, the img link will work for `next export`, otherwise it will be linked to your localhost if your wordpress is not deployed.